# Openfire not updating database

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

I have installed Openfire XMPP server on my linux machine, and everything is working fine except for one thing - for some reason there is some kind of cache mechanism that I can't figure out.

I perform changes on the admin console but the database doesn't change.
I understand there is some sort of cache involved, but how can I stop it? I have external API's querying the database, and the fact the database is not up to date is really a problem.

I am using MySQL and openfire 3.9.3

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information do you want to query?

Comment: Information about available rooms, rooms information, rooms members and such

Comment: You could use the Openfire REST API for that. Look here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/mucservice/readme.html